# Problema con Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, volley

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código

```
static String getAuthorizationToken(Context ctx, String user, String password){
    volley = VolleyS.getInstance(ctx);

    String url = RestUrl.URL_BASE + RestUrl.URL_LOGIN;

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("user", user);
    params.put("password", password);

    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);

    MetaRequest request = new MetaRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            try {
                JSONObject headers = jsonObject.getJSONObject("headers");
                token = headers.getString("Authorization");
              //Aqui token tiene el valor

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("ERROR", Log.getStackTraceString(volleyError));
        }
    });

    volley.addToQueue(request, RESTUtils.class);

    //Aquí token es null
    return token;
}
```

Destacar eque token es una variable statica, el problema que tengo es que al obtener el token, este se guarda solo dentro de la clase interna, pero al acceder a ella desde otra clase, o incluso al final del metodo getAuthorizationToken(), esta devuelve nulo, como si se borrara su contenido y necesito guardar ese token en la variable para poder usarlo posteriormente.

Comment: El problema es que `onResponse` no se ejecuta síncronamente con el resto de tu función, sino cuando llega el evento. Tu función establece el listener del evento, pero no se queda a esperar la recepción. Así que cuando haces el `return token`, no se ha ejecutado `onResponse`. Tienes que modificar la manera de informar de la llegada de este evento y solo entonces, consultar el valor de `token`.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que la respuesta es asíncrona, en este punto el valor seguramente es null:

return token;

ya que la respuesta en realidad se recibe dentro del método `onResponse()`

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
         ...
         ...
}
```

en este caso tienes como opción realizar una petición sincrona, lo puedes realizar de esta forma mediante la clase RequestFuture:

```
  static String getAuthorizationToken(Context ctx, String user, String password){

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);

        String url = RestUrl.URL_BASE + RestUrl.URL_LOGIN;


        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user", user);
        params.put("password", password);


        final JSONObject jsonObjectRequest = new JSONObject(params);

        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonObjectRequest/*new JSONObject()*/, future, null);
        requestQueue.add(request);

        try {

            JSONObject response = future.get(); 
            token = String.valueOf(response);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


        return token;


    }
```